# applicationDidEnterBackground changes navigationColor

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set navigationBar color with the code below added on `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
//Set tint color
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

//Set title attributes
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                      [UIFont fontWithName:@"Pacifico" size:21],
                                                      NSFontAttributeName, [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]];

//Set navigationBar color
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor];
```

everything works good, application starts and colors are correct like the image below

[image: Application on foreground]

Issue happens when I follow these steps:

1. I press home button application enters background.
2. I double press home button to see my application, and there is shown but not in navigationColor **RED** but **BLACK** in gradient with **RED**.
3. I click to open it, it loads again with the color **RED**. (Screenshot below)

Maybe the issue is related to the tabBarController.tabBarColor because I set it to black!

[image: Application on background]

I don't know why is this happening, I don't if there is an issue with global tint or so! Has this problem happened to anyone? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Do it on viewWillAppear:

Comment: I have tried it same results also on viewDidLoad and awakeFromNib

Comment: You're on a real device?

Comment: @DylanGattey Yes iPhone 5, iOS 7.1.1

Comment: Also because I forgot to mention, I tried this also on iPad Air, still the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For those who are having the same issue, this has nothing to do with background or foreground. It is just no content under the TopViews.

Finally I found the solution

**Extend Edges Under Top Bars** was **unchecked**, I did a check on it, and it works.

1. For those who don't know how to show this, go to you viewController on storyboard, click on it.
2. Show the attributes inspector (the fourth button) on the right dock
3. There is a part where is written Extend Edges
4. Check under the top bars, run the application and everything should be fine

[image]

*I don't know what causes this issue to let the navBar change to black (I mean the part which has no content, it is just part of the view)*

Answer (score 0):

The methods you are looking for are not `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:`. You should use `applicationWillResignActive:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Here is how they work. If you minimize the app by pressing the home button once, both `applicationWillResignActive:` and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` are called, in this order. When you maximize your app `applicationWillEnterForeground:` and `applicationDidBecomeActive:` are called, again in the same order. However when you double press the home button to see the recently used apps, only `applicationWillResignActive:` is called, and selecting your app from this view will call `applicationDidBecomeActive:` only. So these are the methods you should use.

A **warning** though, these methods are also called if your app is active and you open the Control Center, or the Notification Center by dragging the bottom / top edge of screen.

Hope you can use this info to your advantage.

Comment: I don't want to use `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidBecomeActive`. I just want to know why the color is becoming with gradient. In a specific viewController I have set it up right, and it isn't going with gradient, I just want to know what causes this to go like I described!

Comment: I apologise. However, I have created a test project and tried it with `UINavigationController`s as the controllers in each tab of a `UITabBarController`, and used the exact same code as you have mentioned in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. In my case it's working fine. Are you sure there isn't any other code in the other methods I have mentioned in my answer? I know a case where changing frames of the `navigationBar` might result in weird behaviour . May we see some code?

Comment: I have set the `barTintColor` on the `UITabBar` too using `[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];` in finish launching. Still works fine.

Comment: Thanks for your point, this should be a nice suggestion. To get it right, you created a ViewController for your navigationControllers (I mean from IB in storyboard) in each tab?